# Loop through nested arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

Im trying to loop through PHP arrays decoded from a json file. I get the results but it only gives me the first results of the arrays in the the file. How can I make it loop? This is my code:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {

  echo $event['d']['Tree1'][0]['Tree2']['Field1'] . '<br>';
  echo $event['d']['Tree1'][0]['Tree2']['Field2'] . '<br>';
  echo $event['d']['Tree1'][0]['Tree2']['Field3'] . '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Look up `foreach` or `while` or `for` in the php manual

Comment: What's the array, what do you get as a result, what do you want?

Comment: If you want help, you had better show us the array, or at least a representative example of it. And tell us what you want as a result.

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: please show the array add that in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to loop through the values of a ["multidimensional array"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You're starting correctly by going through your array with a loop, but then you're stuck because each element in your loop is... another array. So, to echo out the values of the child array, you want to run a second loop inside of your loop. Essentially, if your loop hits a child array, you want to loop through that array too. If you know your array is made of child arrays only, you can do this like so:

```
<?php
foreach ($events as $event) {

    foreach($event as $ev) {

        echo $ev;
    }
}
```

If you need the keys, that adds a slight layer of complexity, but nothing you can't manage.

```
<?php
foreach ($events as $event) {
    foreach ($event as $k=>$v) {
        echo $k .': '. $v; 
    }
}
```

There are some examples in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) as well. You can also add in conditionals if you only need data from specific keys. Good luck!